# What is the difference between setq-mode-local and setq-local

Tags: hooks, cedet, buffer-local

I don't understand how `setq-mode-local` works (mode-local is a package from cedet). 
The macro's documentation says:

> setq-mode-local is a Lisp macro in `mode-local.el'.
>
> (setq-mode-local MODE &rest ARGS)
>
> Assign new values to variables local in MODE.
>   MODE must be a major mode symbol.
>   ARGS is a list (SYM VAL SYM VAL ...).
>   The symbols SYM are variables; they are literal (not evaluated).
>   The values VAL are expressions; they are evaluated.
>   Set each SYM to the value of its VAL, locally in buffers already in
>   MODE, or in buffers switched to that mode.
>   Return the value of the last VAL.

1. Does the mode need to be loaded?
2. How does this differ from just adding a `setq-local` call to a mode-hook?

Comment: I look at the source code and it's quite complex. So it's probably more sophisticated than adding a setq-local to a hook. But I don't know what the difference is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate difference is that `setq-mode-local` will also affect already existing buffers, whereas adding a `setq-local` to the mode hook will only affect future buffers.

Of course, there are other differences due to the underlying mechanisms used, but I think to a first approximation, this is the only real difference.

Comment: `setq-mode-local` doesn't work for me if I enable the appropriate mode in a non-file buffer.
It does work for file buffers though. Is this intended?